# Change order of tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am working in Haskell for an assignment and I can't seem to figure out something which I think should be easy. It is for a line editor.

It is a college assignment and I am not asking for a full editor thanks, just the answer to a question.

I have a tuple `([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])` which basically converts to `(left, right, highlight, copybuffer)`. I want to print it on screen so it displays as `(left, highlight, right, copybuffer)`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you searching for something like `f (x, y, u, v) = (x, u, y, v)`? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching here, and then construct a *new* tuple with the desired order. For example:

```
changeorder :: (a, b, c, d) -> (a, c, b, d)
changeorder (lef, rig, high, copy) = (lef, high, rig, copy)
```

Note that this function has a more generic signature (here `lef`, `rig`, etc. can have different types). As a result we can possibly reuse the function for other problems, or in case you for instance change your mind about the type of one of the parameters for this specific problem.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot :)